# How I can change domain of the running openedx?

Tags: openedx

1. How I can change the domain of the running Openedx ? I wanna to run
   it with new domain.

Comment: Please provide details about your openedx installation, are you using native or tutor so a solution can be recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask or search here https://discuss.openedx.org or here https://discuss.overhang.io in case you are using tutor.

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in your `config.yml` file.

```
# The host names of LMS and Studio. Don't include the "https://" part:
EDXAPP_LMS_BASE: "online.myeducation.org"
EDXAPP_CMS_BASE: "studio.online.myeducation.org"
```